# What's the best for for print ? (a website page)

Tags: css, printing

so what 'font-family' should I use in a print stylesheet?

Comment: I think everyone will agree with me, Comic Sans is universally loved for this

Comment: @nick, lol .. obligatory : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzmrxKhaKRU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep it the same as the screen display - unless there is a good reason for it to be different. Less jarring for the user, who expects the print to look similar to screen.

(By the way, there are some nice print stylesheet tips here - http://css-tricks.com/css-tricks-finally-gets-a-print-stylesheet/)

Comment: From the article you linked: "On the web, the body type for articles here is a sans-serif. On the printed page, I think that serif fonts are easier to read so I reset the font-family to Georgia. No background and black text is the default, but just in case, I explicitly declare it in the body."

Comment: :)
Yep, that is why I said 'I would...' - just my opinion.